Speedup ratio and parallel efficiency of implemented simple parallel matrix multiplication
The following is my source code for parallel calculation matrix multiplication, which tests the parallel efficiency obtained by the number of 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, and 32 threads, respectively.
My Operating Environment:
Physical CPU: Intel i5 (4 cores), 16GB of memory
Virtual machine environment: Ubuntu 20.04.6 (64-bit version), gcc version 9.4.0 20210601
Run the following command to compile and run the source code:
gcc -fopenmp -o mul MatrixMul.c 
./mul 32

(32 indicates the number of threads.) Multiple parameters are acceptable, and the default default is 1 threads
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

// Number of threads
int n_threads = 1;

// Matrix dimensions
int n = 1000; // The number of rows of A
int m = 3000; // The number of columns for A and the number of rows for B
int p = 1000; // Number of columns for B
// Matrices A, B, C
int **A, **B, **C;

// Initialize the A and B matrices and allocate space to the C matrice
void init() {
    A = (int **)calloc(n, sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        A[i] = (int *)calloc(m, sizeof(int));
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            A[i][j] = i + 1 + j;
        }
    }
    B = (int **)calloc(m, sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        B[i] = (int *)calloc(p, sizeof(int));
        for (int j = 0; j < p; j++) {
            B[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
    C = (int **)calloc(n, sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        C[i] = (int *)calloc(p, sizeof(int));
        for (int j = 0; j < p; j++) {
            C[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Set the number of threads
    if (argc >= 2) n_threads = atoi(argv[1]);
    // Set up the matrix dimensions
    if (argc >= 3) n = atoi(argv[2]);
    if (argc >= 4) m = atoi(argv[3]);
    if (argc >= 5) p = atoi(argv[4]);

    //Initialize the matrix
    init();

    // Set the number of threads
    omp_set_num_threads(n_threads);

    // The timer begins
    double ts = omp_get_wtime();

    // Calculate C
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < p; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    // 3 columns in the first 3 rows of output matrix C
    printf("Matrix C: \n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j =0; j < 3; j++){
            printf("%d ",C[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    //The timer ends
    double te = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("Time: %f s\n", te - ts);

    // Free up matrix memory
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) free(A[i]);
    free(A);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) free(B[i]);
    free(B);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) free(C[i]);
    free(C);

    return 0;
}

Theoretically, the parallel efficiency should not exceed 1, why did I calculate the parallel efficiency to exceed 1. I'm a beginner in parallel computing and would like to be helped, thanks.

Why aren't you using compiler optimisations? Performance measurements on unoptimised code is fairly meaningless. please show a [mre] including all input and output of the program

The title talks about C++, the question is about MatrixMul.c and the compiler GCC, and tagged as C++. Can you decide which single language you are using?

Measuring performance inside a VM is also likely to lead to strange results

On my machine without compiler optimisations I get a maximum speedup over the single threaded version of around 10, with compiler optimisations the speedup is around 7 both of which seem reasonable for a 12 core CPU

You should really use flatten array instead of inefficient jagged arrays. Then please use -O3, and at least -mavx2 (AFAIR supported on all CPU released <= 10 years ago). Compilers generate code for 20 years old CPUs by default for sake of retro-compatibility (at the expense of slower codes). Also please use the env variable OMP_NUM_THREADS instead of the non-standard omp_set_num_threads (the former is also more flexible for end-users and even for debugging).

Oh and btw, be aware that "Intel i5" means nothing. What matters is the full reference : e.g. i5-9600KF. There is a huge difference for example between the i5-14600K and the i5-6600U CPU: both are "i5" but the former is a recent mid-end big-little CPU targeting PCs and the later is a low-end pretty-old CPU targeting low-power notebooks.

Oh and last but not least: you include the time of the printfs in the timings which is always a bad idea!

@JérômeRichard Those are all sound comments. I think you could post them as an answer to the question.
